# How to add extra leftmargin only for the body in an environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments, margins, leftmargin

How to add extra left-margin only for the body in an environment? The extra margin should be of same space as the `environment-head` occupies. For example, what I am getting is this:

[image]

And what I want is this:

[image]

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        \lipsum [1]
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Please help. Thanks.

**Reply to @John Kormylo's answer:**

problem with `alignat` environment

[image: problem with <code>alignat</code> environment]

problem with `enumerate` environment

[image]

problem with nested `claim` environment

[image: problem with nested <code>claim</code> environment]

Answer (score 4):

See if the following may help you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newlength\myproof
\settowidth\myproof{Proof. }

\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\myproof}
        \lipsum [1]
        \end{minipage}\vskip-\baselineskip
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

You can define new environment, for example:

```
\newenvironment{Proof}%
    {
    \begin{proof}\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\myproof}
    }
    {
    \end{minipage}\vskip-\baselineskip
    \end{proof}
    }
```

and than use it for example as:

```
\begin{Proof}
    \lipsum[66]
\end{Proof}
```

and will get

[image]

but with it you will have less flexibility with placing of square on the end of proof. In some circumstances can happen, that you will need to delete you `\vskip-\baselineskip` after `\end{minipage` In such a cases you can use the first solution.

Comment: thanks a lot. It is working. I just changed `\settowidth\myproof{Proof. }` to `\settowidth\myproof{\textsc{Proof.} }`. Can you please instruct me how to redefine my environments so that I do not have to begin and end the `minipage` everytime I call an environment?

Comment: @SubhajitPaul, see addendum to answer.

Comment: I am extremely sorry to un-accept your answer. The portions of my file on which I applied your suggestion did not give me a picture of what happens when a proof continues to the next page. Certainly, I don't want to start a proof at the next page leaving a blank half-page. Thanks to @John Kormylo for bringing this up. The fault of not testing your answer completely lies entirely upon me.

Answer (score 1):

This version modifies the amsthm proof environment.  The advantage is that you can break the page in the middle of a proof.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
    \savebox{\@tempboxa}{\hskip\labelsep\itshape#1\@addpunct{.}}% added code
    \labelwidth=\wd\@tempboxa
    \advance\leftskip by \labelwidth
    \advance\linewidth by -\labelwidth
    \advance\@totalleftmargin by \labelwidth
    \leftmargin=\labelwidth
  \item[\box\@tempboxa]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse  
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{proof}
        \lipsum [1]

        \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
        \begin{itemize}
          \item nesting test
        \end{itemize}
        \begin{flalign}
          \text{left} && \text{center} && \text{right}
        \end{flalign}
    \end{proof}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The good point is it is doing justice for breaking the page in the middle or placing the `qed` at the end of the proof, but it is not behaving well with other environments like `enumerate` or `alignat*`. Also, it is not accepting the `claim` environment written using @Zarko 's technique. Please see the edit in the question. Please instruct me how to modify the `claim` environment to make it act in the nested way inside the `proof`.

Comment: I have edited the question with your suggestions. If you need I will share MWE for those portions.

Comment: I cannot figure out how to indent equations.  One can demonstrate that lists do it, but none of the parameters associated with lists seem to have any effect.